# В каких случаях может быть полезно использование класса Proxy в js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

В основном интересует Node.js, но на фронтенде тоже будет интересно.

Comment: Для отладки очень удобно. Ещё можно что-то mobx-подобное через него сделать. А вообще, хороший вопрос!